# Stop `exit` from running

Tags: macos, zsh, pathfinder

When I run terminal within Pathfinder, typing `exit` is just a mistake (blocks the Window for nothing).

How may I

1. Figure out I'm in Pathfinder
2. Suppress `exit` in Zshell if I am in Pathfinder?

Comment: The hard part here is 1. First thing I would do is compare the output of `env | sort` between when it is run from within Pathfinder's terminal and some other terminal. There could be some environment variables that are only set by Pathfinder or set to a value that indicates Pathfinder.

Comment: @Adaephon what if we ignore #1... I could run a script with "Run command:" on startup (Path Finder preferences).... what command would I run?

Comment: You can disable `exit` by running `alias exit=` inside the shell or the shells configuration. If this works with "Run command" depends on how the command there is executed.

Comment: This actually works!

http://i.imgur.com/JkCY0g8.png

If you want to place an answer, please, I can mark it as accepted etc. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exit` is a built-in of *zsh*. The easiest way to disable it - or any other command - is to create an alias with the same name that does nothing:

```
alias exit=
```

or maybe prints a short message to be a bit more informative:

```
alias exit='echo "Sorry, but I cannot do that."'
```

To run this automatically for shell sessions  inside Pathfinder, set it in the "Run command" field in Pathfinder's settings.

---

**Note:** an alias is always scoped to the session of *zsh* in which it was defined. It will not carry over to any other *zsh* session you start from there, so `exit` will still work normally these other sessions. Also, aliases set in a child session of *zsh* will not carry over to the parent session.

That also means that you cannot just run a script to set aliases or make any other changes to the current shell environment. But you can use the `source` command to execute commands from a script in the current shell session.

Instead of setting `alias exit=` in "Run command" you can then set the following (as noted in a comment by the OP):

```
source /path/to/some/script_with_settings
```

with `/path/to/some/script_with_settings` containing:

```
alias exit=
```

possibly among other things.

Comment: How does this change if I want to put it in a script instead?

Comment: `source path/to/script` worked...